# How to make Scrolling background. Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, background

I am trying to build a game in which the player moves to the right. I also want the background to move in the opposite direction of the player movement. How to achieve this ?? I need it to look like the flappy bird background.I am not using spriteKit or swift. An error keeps showing up saying "invalid suffix xscreenwidth on integer constant".

I want it to look like this background http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RkGUk40LkrQ But the only thing I can find are in spriteKit.

I need it in UIKit I have this so far:

It says 
    No visible @interface for UIView declares  selector initWithImage, No visible @interface for UIView declares  selector addSubView, and No visible @interface for UIView declares  selector beginTheAnimation

```
#import "Game.h"    
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface Game ()

{

    AVAudioPlayer *_soundEffect;

}

@property (nonatomic) int screenHeight;    
@property (nonatomic) int screenWidth;

@end

@implementation Game

-(int)screenHeight{
    return self.view.frame.size.height;
}

-(int)screenWidth{
    return self.view.frame.size.width;
}


//Preparation
-(void)prepareToAnimate{

    CGRect startingPosition = CGRectMake(0,0,2xscreenWidth,screenHeight);
    //You will need to define a variable for your screenWidth and screenHeight

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bgtest2.png"];
    //Add your image name here. It should be a double image (i.e. the whole image that fits on an iphone screen next to a duplicate of itself so that it is twice the width)

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    [self addSubView:imageView];
    [self beginTheAnimation];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The multiplication operator is `*`, not `x`. The error is showing because you have `2xscreenWidth` in this line:

```
CGRect startingPosition = CGRectMake(0,0,2xscreenWidth,screenHeight);
```

Change it to:

```
CGRect startingPosition = CGRectMake(0,0,2*screenWidth,screenHeight);
```

Comment: Is there another way to do this, I tried changing x to * but now more erros show up. The only things I can find on this is for spriteKit.

Comment: Your theory seems fine to me, it just looks like you have errors to resolve. You need to fix the errors in your code before you can continue or before anyone can properly help you.

Comment: Im new to stackoverflow, the comment section wont let me post what the erros say so i edited the main question.

Comment: `addSubView` should be `addSubview`. `UIView alloc` should be `UIImageView alloc`. It looks like you haven't defined a `beginTheAnimation` function; you should do that. It seems like you could benefit a lot from some basic tutorials in programming. Try searching the internet for Objective-C programming tutorials so that you can learn how to debug simple errors like the ones you have made above. You have a lot of learning to do before you can create a Flappy Bird clone.